# setting IsDirty field in kendo gantt chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-gantt, dirty-checking

In a simple example like this - https://dojo.telerik.com/UViBAZAP How to mark the field dirty? I want to make changes first and then save at one go.

Edit- I want the field on the UI to show that it was edited. like it does in kendo grid.

Comment: Your link points to the start page and no particular example.

Comment: updated the code link

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to maintain the [dirty](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model/fields/dirty) field yourself, you just need to ensure that when you modify one of the model objects in the datasource, you use the [set](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject/methods/set) method, instead of assigning to it's fields directly.

```
var task1 = $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt").dataSource.data()[0];
console.log(task1.dirty); // returns false
task1.set("title","Task1 (modified)");
console.log(task1.dirty); // returns true
```

This way, kendo is aware of the change and marks the object as dirty for you. The datasource will also consider this a change which needs to be sync'd. Hope that helps.

https://dojo.telerik.com/UViBAZAP/2

Comment: Right, however the field doesnt show that it was edited, like it happens in kendo grid. It does not append span with k-dirty class to the cell.